# Adding new elements to std::list

Tags: c++

I'm currently experiencing a problem adding a new object to a std::list.
Indeed:

```
cout << "Size before: " << m_treeList.size() << endl; // Shows 0
Tree* newTree = new Tree(name);
cout << newTree->getName() << endl; // Shows name as expected
m_treeList.push_back(*newTree);
cout << m_treeList.back().getName() << endl; // Shows nothing
cout << "Size after:" << m_treeList.size() << endl; // Shows 1
```

I'm creating a new tree initialized with a name. I can print this name fine. However, when I add the newTree to the list of trees, it appears to not contain anything, but the size does increment. What is going on here?

Comment: You are pushing a _copy_ of the tree when you dereference it (assuming the container is of type `List<Tree>`). Are you sure your copy constructor is working correctly?

Comment: I did not implement the copy constructor. It seems to work correctly now. Thanks a lot! Missed that one.

Comment: Wasn't this same question just asked yesterday? Did someone in your class say "just ask it on Stack Overflow"?

Comment: Do you really need to dynamically allocate a `Tree` only to copy it into your `std::list`? If not you can just do: `m_treeList.emplace_back(name);`